# Permissions to Django Admin Actions

Tags: python, django, permissions, django-admin, django-admin-actions

I have written some custom actions for my django project, however cannot work out how to make them available to only superusers. I have tried putting an if statement round the actions line with Users.is_superuser but it keeps giving me an error saying there is no attribute called is_superuser.

Here is my admin.py file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from models import Art, Agent, UserProfile
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, User, AbstractUser
from django.contrib.auth import *
from import_export import resources
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin

#admin.site.unregister(Group)

def approve_art(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    queryset.update(authenticate = "approved")

def reject_art(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    queryset.update(authenticate = "rejected")

# Add in this class to customized the Admin Interface
class ArtAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id', 'identification', 'name', 'artist', 'category', 'type', 'agent', 'authenticate', ]
    search_fields = ('name', 'category', 'artist', 'id', 'authenticate', )

    actions = [approve_art, reject_art]
    list_filter = ["authenticate"]




class AgentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id', 'name', 'phone', 'postcode', ]
    search_fields = ('name', 'id', )

class ArtResource(resources.ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = Art

# Update the registeration to include this customised interface
admin.site.register(Art, ArtAdmin)
admin.site.register(Agent, AgentAdmin)
```

Comment: Please include the code where you added an `if` statement.

Comment: I took out the line when I was trying different things but it was in the ArtAdmin class just before actions and all it was was if User.is_superuser:

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can customize the list of actions by overriding `get_actions()`. For example:

```
class ArtAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
        list_display = ['id', 'identification', 'name', 'artist', 'category', 'type', 'agent', 'authenticate', ]
        search_fields = ('name', 'category', 'artist', 'id', 'authenticate', )
        list_filter = ["authenticate"]
        actions = [approve_art, reject_art]
   
        def get_actions(self, request):
            actions = super(ArtAdmin, self).get_actions(request)
            if not request.user.is_superuser:
               del actions[approve_art]
               del actions[reject_art]
            return actions
```

Check out https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#conditionally-enabling-or-disabling-actions for more info

Comment: You need to call parent classes `get_actions` method first I guess like this: `actions = super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_actions(request)` and return them in order to keep other actions though.

Comment: Yeah noticed that just after I posted, its been updated now

Answer (score 5):

Update for Django >= 2.1

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#setting-permissions-for-actions

in a nutshell:

```
def make_published(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    queryset.update(status='p')
make_published.allowed_permissions = ('change',)
```

or custom:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import get_permission_codename

class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    actions = ['make_published']

    def make_published(self, request, queryset):
        queryset.update(status='p')
    make_published.allowed_permissions = ('publish',)

    def has_publish_permission(self, request):
        """Does the user have the publish permission?"""
        opts = self.opts
        codename = get_permission_codename('publish', opts)
        return request.user.has_perm('%s.%s' % (opts.app_label, codename))
```

(Example code all taken from the linked documentation.)

Answer (score 1):

Considering that an action is not `ModelAdmin`-dependant, the best way to prevent it from being run by an non-authorized user remains to check it inside the action:

```
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied

def approve_art(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    if not request.user.is_superuser:
        raise PermissionDenied
    queryset.update(authenticate = "approved")
```

Which is [how django handles it for the `delete_selected` action](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.9/django/contrib/admin/actions.py#L28-L30).

The action would still remain available on the dropdown list though, but will return a 403 HTTP code.

Answer (score 0):

You can override your ModelAdmin's `get_actions` method like this:

```
def get_actions(self, request):
    actions = super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_actions(request)
    if request.user.is_superuser:
            actions.update(dict(youraction=youraction))
    return actions
```

Here the [documentation materials](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_actions) you may want to look at.

Answer (score 0):

Only for **superusers**, you can display **`approve_art` and `reject_art` admin actions** by overriding [get_actions()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_actions) as shown below:

```py
class ArtAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):

    # ...

    actions = ["approve_art", "reject_art"]

    def get_actions(self, request):
        actions = super().get_actions(request)
        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            del actions["approve_art"]
            del actions["reject_art"]
        return actions
```